# Centos 6 Gnome Corrupted screen, "while loading OAFIID:Gnote"

Tags: centos, gnome

I have an issue after unlocking the screen which has been locked either manually or via the automatic screen saver.

Returning to the user desktop, the screen is completely the "background" color and there is a dialog saying

> The panel encountered an problem while loading "OAFIID:GnoteApplet". Do you want to delete the applet from your configuration".

However, moving the mouse reveals the "real" desktop underneath. The dialog is only an image.  Moving the mouse around gradually reveals the real screen.

[image: Here you can see a terminal window hidden by the 'fake' screen]

I have no idea what this means or how to fix it...  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Booting the system to X11 **without** an `xorg.conf` file causes this behavior on certain new motherboards.

I fixed it by adding an `xorg.conf` file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` which specifies to use the vesa driver:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "vesa"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Unfortunately, we have a mixture of old and new motherboards.  Adding the xorg.conf file on the old motherboards makes X not start up at all.  So we have to manage on a case-by-case basis.